# who is the of author of CN 101463502 B?

Tags: patentability, claims, disclosure

who is the author of the patent number CN 101463502 B## Heading ## entitled Pineapple leaf fiber biochemical degumming technique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Patents do not have *authors*, they have *inventors* and they have *applicants*. Typing the document number into google patents immediately brings the answer up. Only Chinese names of the inventors are shown.
 [image]

Comment: thank you very much...
i also want to ask...what is the difference between the inventors and applicants?
i am just confused between the two terms..
thank you

Comment: Inventors are the actual people who had the novel idea. Applicants might be those same people or might be a company or a person that the inventors work for or sold the invention to. After the patent issues the applicant owns the patent and can sell it to yet another person or company who would then the owner.